# How to create a navigation bar that is transparent as it scrolls, and to remove the spaces in between each item

Tags: css, blogger

I am totally new to CSS and I'm trying to make a top navigation bar in Blogger, that is transparent as it scrolls.

This is what I want to get: A top-fixed navigation bar that is slightly transparent as it scrolls, a shadow below the bar.

See image: http://s27.postimg.org/qgxq63z5f/Screen_Shot_2014_01_08_at_3_51_09_PM.png

However, after trying out, this is what I got: Awful gaps between each item, and no opacity whatsoever.

See image: http://s17.postimg.org/bf8m8jtwv/Screen_Shot_2014_01_08_at_3_28_59_PM.png

How can I figure this out? Here is my code:

```
#nav {
z-index: 999; 
position: fixed;
top: 8px;
padding-bottom:10px;
margin-left:0px;
font: 22px Garamond;
list-style-type: none;
width: 1000px;
text-align: center; /*set to left, center, or right to align the menu as desired*/
}
#nav a {
display: inline;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 11px;
margin-right: 10px;
border-bottom: none;
background-color: #ffffff;
color: #000000;
}
#nav a:hover {
background-color:#ffffff;
color: #dddddd;
}
#nav b:scroll {
background: #ffffff;
height: 30px;
width: 1000px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
position: relative;
z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: The HTML would help. FYI people can help easier if you prepare a gist / codepen or similar. Also is the b tag really used - what for?

Comment: Well, your anchors have a white background, since you set it as white. You either need opacity: 0.7 (or so) or a rgba value as color. Furthermore, your #nav should have a background to fill the gaps, not the anchors.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
    opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
```

and for shadow (bottom shadow)

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

ofcourse you can adjust the numbers to your expected result

Answer (score 0):

You do not need #nav :scroll. All you need to do is add a background color to the container nav and give it an opacity.

```
#nav {


/*adjust numbers for box shadow for top/right/bottom/left*/
       -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.75);

/* Required for IE 5, 6, 7 */
/* ...or something to trigger hasLayout, like zoom: 1; */
width: 100%; 

/* Theoretically for IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */   
/* ...but not required as filter works too */
/* should come BEFORE filter */
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

/* This works in IE 8 & 9 too */
/* ... but also 5, 6, 7 */
filter: alpha(opacity=50);

/* Older than Firefox 0.9 */
-moz-opacity:0.5;

/* Safari 1.x (pre WebKit!) */
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;

/* Modern!
/* Firefox 0.9+, Safari 2?, Chrome any?
/* Opera 9+, IE 9+ */
opacity: 0.5;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove background color from all other div add add it as `rgba` to `#nav`

We use `rgba` instead of `opacity` to avoid being semi-transparent children.

```
/* 0.5 is your opacity while others are rgb color code */
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
```

**Edit:** And Shadow as mentioned by @user2211216

So, here is your final code. You can replace this with your existing. (I don't know why you used `b:scroll` still I included here)

```
#nav {
z-index: 999; 
position: fixed;
top: 8px;
padding-bottom:10px;
margin-left:0px;
font: 22px Garamond;
list-style-type: none;
width: 1000px;
text-align: center;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);/* 0.5 is opacity */

-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
#nav a {
display: inline;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 11px;
margin-right: 10px;
border-bottom: none;
color: #000000;
}
#nav a:hover {
color: #dddddd;
}
#nav b:scroll {
height: 30px;
width: 1000px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
position: relative;
z-index: 9999;
}
```